# How to get order id and print details on success page after order creating programmatically in Magento 1.9.x

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I am using Magento 1.9.x and I would like to create an order via quote and I can do that like this:

```
    private function createOrder()
{
    $orderId = $session->getTransactionId();
    $quote = $this->_getCheckout()->getQuote();
    $quote->setReservedOrderId($orderId);
    $quote->collectTotals()->getPayment()->setMethod($this->_getPaymentMethod());
    $quoteId = $quote->getId();
    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
    $service->submitAll();
    $order = $service->getOrder();
    $order->setStatus('complete');
    $order->save();
    $checkoutSession = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getCheckout();
    $checkoutSession->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quoteId);
    $checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($quoteId);
    $checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getIncrementId());
}

protected function _getCheckout()
{
    return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
}

protected function _getPaymentMethod()
{
    return $this->_getCheckout()->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod();
}
```

But my problem is the success page. When I redirect to the success page just appear like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBWu1.png)

Not appear order id or print detail like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cv3Wr.png)

How can I fix it?

Thank you
Edit:

I want to create a custom payment method. If the customer choose my method I delete the "Place Order" button and I create iframe at order review.

app\design\frontend\base\default\layout\mymodule.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <checkout_onepage_review>
        <reference name="checkout.onepage.review.button">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template helper="mymodule/data/getReviewButtonTemplate">
                    <name>mymodule/onepage/iframe.phtml</name>
                    <block>checkout.onepage.review.button</block>
                </template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </checkout_onepage_review>
</layout>
```

app\code\local\Mycompany\Mymodule\Helper\data.php

```
 <?php

class Mycompany_Mymodules_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{


      public function getHostedUrl()
        {
            //get iframe url from soap
        }

    public function GetHostedPaymentProcessStatusResult()
    {
        //check from soap response is correct
    }

    public function getReviewButtonTemplate($name, $block)
    {
        $paymentcode = $this->_getPaymentMethod();

        if ($paymentcode == 'mymodule')
            return $name;
        if ($blockObject = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock($block))
            return $blockObject->getTemplate();
        return '';
    }
  public function getConfigData($configName)
{
    return Mage::getStoreConfig('payment/mymodule/' . $configName, Mage::app()->getStore());
}
    protected function _getCheckout()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    }

    protected function _getPaymentMethod()
    {
        return $this->_getCheckout()->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod();
    }
}
```

Payment is complete at in iframe and calls my module response page with some parameters.

app\code\local\Mycompany\Mymodule\controllers\PaymentController.php

```
    <?php

class Mycompany_Mymodule_PaymentController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function responseAction()
    {
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
        $transactionId = $_GET['TransactionId'];
        $orderId = $session->getTransactionId();
        $mymoduleTransId = $_GET['MymoduleTransId'];
        $helper = Mage::helper('mymodule');
        if ($_GET['Result'] == 'PaymentOk' && $transactionId == $orderId) {
            $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
            $result = $helper->getHostedPaymentProcessStatus($transactionId, $mymoduleTransId);
            if ($result) {
                $result = $result->GetHostedPaymentProcessStatusResult;
                $resultCode = $result->ResultCode;
                if ($resultCode === "Success") {
                    $quote->setReservedOrderId($orderId);
                    $quoteId = $quote->getId();

                    $quote->collectTotals()->getPayment()->setMethod($this->_getPaymentMethod());

                    $service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
                    $service->submitAll();
                    $order = $service->getOrder();
                    $order->setStatus(Mage::helper('mymodule')->getConfigData('after_pay_status'));
                    $order->save();

                    $checkoutSession = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/type_onepage')->getCheckout();

                    $checkoutSession->setLastSuccessQuoteId($quoteId);
                    $checkoutSession->setLastQuoteId($quoteId);
                    $checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getIncrementId());

                    $this->_clearQuote($quoteId);
                    $returnUrl = Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/success', array('_secure' => true));
                } else
                    $returnUrl = Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/failure', array('_secure' => true));
            } else {
                $returnUrl = Mage::getUrl('checkout/onepage/failure', array('_secure' => true));
            }
            echo '<script> window.top.location.href = "' . $returnUrl . '";</script>';
        }
    }

    protected function _getCheckout()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    }

    protected function _getPaymentMethod()
    {
        return $this->_getCheckout()->getQuote()->getPayment()->getMethod();
    }

    protected function _clearQuote($quoteID)
    {
        $quote = Mage::getModel("sales/quote")->load($quoteID);
        $quote->setIsActive(0)->save();
        $quote->delete();
        $quote->save();

        $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
        $quoteItems = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')
            ->getQuote()
            ->getItemsCollection();
        foreach ($quoteItems as $item) {
            $cart->removeItem($item->getId());
        }
        $cart->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: you can get it using sesson

Answer (score 0):

The best way (and actually I believe this is the way magento uses) is to pass the order ID into session. To do that, use `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());`. 
Then on success page just use `Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());` to retrieve order's Increment ID.

Comment: nope it's not my problem solution. But I find solution its my stupidness, I set orderId as orderIncrementId so I set 
                    $checkoutSession->setLastOrderId($order->getId()); and solved.